# stripe.redirectToCheckout not working in mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkout

I am using Stripe to integrate iDeal checkout in my pizzeria website. The process is split up into two parts:

1. Some javascript to call the checkout .NET (asmx) webservice

   ```
       function iDealCheckout() {

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "iDealSession.asmx/CreateiDealSession",
           data: "{'Guid':'" + bestelguid + "'}",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {
               //alert("session Id: " + data.d.sessionId + " totaal: " + data.d.totaal);
               Id = data.d.sessionId;
               var stripe = Stripe('--------------------------------------'); //key is masked here

               stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                   // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
                   // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
                   // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
                   sessionId: Id
               }).then(function (result) {
                   // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                   // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                   // using `result.error.message`.
                   alert(result.error.message);
               });
           },
           error: function () {
               alert("CreateiDealSession mislukt");
           }
       });
   }
   ```

The ajax call returns a Session ID that is used to call stripe.redirectToCheckout which redirects to the iDeal payment page.

2. An .asmx webmethod that returns the Session ID:

   ```
   public class values
   {
       public string sessionId;
       public string totaal;
   }

   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
   public values CreateiDealSession(string Guid)
   {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       string query = "SELECT * FROM Bestellingen WHERE Hashcode=@Guid";
       string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pizzas"].ConnectionString;
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
           {
               cmd.Connection = con;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Guid", Guid);
               using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
               {
                   sda.Fill(dt);
               }
           }
       }

       double totaal = 0;
       foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
           double stukprijs = double.Parse(row["Prijs"].ToString());
           var subtotaal = stukprijs * int.Parse(row["Aantal"].ToString());
           totaal += subtotaal;
       }

       totaal = totaal * 100;
       long amount = Convert.ToInt32(totaal);

       StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "-------------------------------------"; //apikey is masked here

       var options = new SessionCreateOptions
       {
           PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
           {
               "ideal",
           },
           LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
           {
               new SessionLineItemOptions
               {
                   Name = "Uw bestelling bij pizzeria I Colori",
                   Description = "Pasta's & Pizza's",
                   Amount = amount,
                   Currency = "eur",
                   Quantity = 1,
               },
           },
           SuccessUrl = "https://pizzeria.aspworld.nl/Success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
           CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
       };

       var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();
       Stripe.Checkout.Session session = service.Create(options);
       values values = new values();
       values.sessionId = session.Id;
       values.totaal = amount.ToString();
       return values;
   }
   ```

Now all of this is running without problems in mobile and desktop Chrome and Firefox, and the browser redirects to the iDeal payment page. But the stripe.redirectToCheckout does not work in mobile Safari, both Android and iOS.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you have any luck solving your problem?

Comment: No, still not solved.

Comment: In my case, the checkout page was supposed to open in a new tab, but for some reason, Safari was blocking it. As soon as I set it to open in the same tab, the problem was fixed. However, I am not using "stripe.redirectToCheckout" as it seems it's already deprecated, so I am not sure if the cause of your problem is the same. Does "stripe.redirectToCheckout" open the checkout in a new tab? If yes, then that might be the problem.